# The figure (number) 5 looks too light in TeX-Gyre Pagella (tgpagella)

Tags: fonts

The number 5 looks too light compared to the other figures. I am using pdflatex with the `tgpagella` package.

[image: Figures]

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
1234567890

Look at the 5:
\blindenumerate[7]

Again, with a little more text:
\Blindenumerate[7]

\end{document}
```

I see no warnings in the pdflatex output. I'm using TeXlive 2020 on a Mac.

Comment: [I get this in tl 2020 from your test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIndO.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it is some problem with my installation? Do you have an idea how I could isolate that? Interestingly, the PDF only has one font, `pdffonts numbers_demo.pdf` says `DXUWKX+TeXGyrePagella-Regular        Type 1            Custom`

Comment: Not really, also I know nothing about the Mac so can't help with debugging there. If you use luatex and fontspec and `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` is the 5 OK ?

Comment: Ha, interesting. The 5 looks fine (just like in your screenshot) when I use lualatex and `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` as you suggested.

Comment: And on the PDF that's generated by lualatex, `pdffonts` says `GADXFO+TeXGyrePagella-Regular        CID Type 0C`. So maybe the 5 is wrong in the `Type 1` encoding? Can I somehow get a log that shows the font files that are actually used by latex / lualatex?

Comment: pdflatex shows the full path to each of the type 1 files it iincludes at the end of the log

Comment: I switched to LuaLaTeX in the end, there the number 5 looks right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle — I am going crazy from reading reports from my students with this issue now with PDFs generated in overleaf

Comment: @WillRobertson well clearly you should fail any student who doesn't use fontspec

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm pretty happy they're using tgpagella, tbh

Comment: @WillRobertson I don't see this on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/btcrpzqvkhnq

Comment: @DavidCarlisle — on the contrary, I see it plainly in that example. So it must be OS dependent?? I also see it in downloaded PDF files, not just Overleaf.